# Atom syntax theme

Tags: atom-editor

Is it possible to have custom font or images in your Atom theme?
I have put the font file in **styles** folder of my theme and created CSS but I get a path error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///usr/share/atom/resources/app.asar/static/font.ttf

**ui-variables.less**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: font;
    src: url('./font.ttf');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/including-font-awesome/10526/3) and [How do I load google fonts into my editor’s styles?](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-load-google-fonts-into-my-editors-styles/8321).

There are two ways to solve your problem,

You can put your ttf file into your styles folder and update your path to `atom://your-package-name/resources/your-font.woff(for instance)`.

**Or**
Drop the font file into the static folder:

```
/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/static
```

Then you can use it in this way,
and then in my styles.less I added the font-face:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: dejavu;
   src: url('dejavu/ttf/dejavusansmono.ttf');
}

html, body, .editor {
   font-family: dejavu;
}
```

: )

Comment: Don't work there is no themes stuff in the /usr/share/atom/resources/app.asar/static/styles/ folder

Comment: @lars1595 Just update the answer, could you try that again?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use an alternative font in your syntax or UI-theme Tyler's solution is the easiest approach.
Though, if by "custom images" you're intention is to add a custom file icons to a UI-theme, the implementation is quite a bit more involved. Basically, you'll need an icon font that contains the images you'd like to include and override the default icons used by Atom. You can use an existing font like [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) or you can use something like [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) to create your own custom icon font from SVG's.
As for overriding Atom's default icons, the easiest way of finding the necessary selectors and styling would probably be referencing the implementation of an existing theme. Feel free to check out my UI-theme [Atomic Design UI](https://github.com/JonSn0w/atomic-design-ui), where I've used an icon font to add custom file icons to the tabs and tree-view. The icon implementation and formatting can be found in the following files:

- `styles/icon-font.less`
- `styles/icon-variables.less`
- `styles/icons.less`